# React state missing properties after setting new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have the following function that a button triggers:

```
function handleRemoveItem (index) {
    const items = [...form[itemName]]
    items.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(items)
    //setForm({ ...form, [itemName]: items })
  }
```

The `itemName` is passed by another function, don't worry about it. 
I'm using react to create an app. The `items` constant looks like this when the function is triggered:

```
[
    0: {id: 8, productName: 'Product 1', stock: 20, expiration: '2025-07-01', lab: 2}
    1: {id: 2, productName: 'Product 2', stock: 7, expiration: '2024-08-01', lab: 3}
    2: {id: 15, productName: 'Product 3', stock: 4, expiration: '2024-09-01', lab: 2}
]
```

Each object has an `id` attribute. The function is used to remove an object from that array and works perfectly fine when the fourth line is commented but I need the React state updated in order to work with it.

So, here is the problem: 
When the fourth line is commented the object look like this (assume the `index` parameter is 1):

```
[
    0: {id: 8, productName: 'Product 1', stock: 20, expiration: '2025-07-01', lab: 2}
    1: {id: 15, productName: 'Product 3', stock: 4, expiration: '2024-09-01', lab: 2}
]
```

Perfectly fine, each objects remain intact but when I uncommented that line (so the state can be updated) it look like this:

```
[
    0: {id: 8, productName: 'Product 1', stock: 20, expiration: '2025-07-01', lab: 2}
    1: {productName: 'Product 3', stock: 4, expiration: '2024-09-01', lab: 2}
]
```

The `id` from the second object is missing, and I don't know why because the code remains the same, only with that line uncommented. The console logs it before the state updates and throws me that array. The weird thing is only affected the forward objects. For example if I remove the first object then the `id` attribute disappear for the next 2, but if I remove the last one the first 2 remains intact.

I tried a lot of things, I even asked ChatGPT what's happening. I tried to use `.map()` instead of `.splice()` but nothing works, not even with `.filter()` or `.slice()`. I even tried to take all the id's and put them together again and nothing works.

I don't know what I'm missing, maybe it's a react thing that I'm not aware of. Any ideas?

Comment: what is `form` object??

Comment: `the third line`? the third line inside the function is `console.log(items)`? That wouldn't cause the issue - `the third line` of the code you posted is `items.splice(index, 1)` ... that too wouldn't cause that issue

Comment: How are you viewing the state at each step in the process? Are you using the React Dev Tools to inspect component state or are you just logging? If the latter, how, where and what **exactly** are you logging

Comment: Ideally you should use the functional update format since your new value depends on the current one... `setForm((f) => ({ ...f, [itemName]: f[itemName].toSpliced(index, 1) }))` but I doubt this is your current problem

Comment: Fourth line* sorry, my bad, the line causing the issue is the fourth line

Comment: I'm actually using console.log in both the items and the form, i even send the info to the backend to see what information arrives, and it's the same, id is gone for some reason

Comment: i don't know what do you mean @ShyamMittal, can you be more specific?

Comment: I suspect something else is changing one of your array items. When you log, try using `console.log("snapshot:", JSON.stringify(whatever))` so you're seeing a snapshot of the data at the time you're logging. It would help if you edited your question to show where and how you're using `console.log()`

Comment: mmm weird, with the console.log() you showed to me the items and the form looks like everything is ok i put 2 console.log i this order: 
`function handleRemoveItem (index) {
    const items = [...form[itemName]]
    items.splice(index, 1)
    console.log('snapshot:', JSON.stringify(items))
    // setExtendedItem(extendedItem.splice(index, 1))
    setForm({ ...form, [itemName]: items })
    console.log('snapshot:', JSON.stringify(form))
  }`
as you can see i console log the `items` and the `form state` the output looks good i'll put it in the next comment

Comment: The output is this: 
`snapshot: [
{"id":8,"productName":"Product 1","stock":20,"expiration":"2025-07-01","lab":2},{"id":15,"productName":"Product 3","stock":4,"expiration":"2024-09-01","lab":2}
]`
so in this case the id didn't disappeared, why does it work like this? and how should i handle the data, i need the javascript object